# Reload UITableView before didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableviewcell with a weak reference of tableview(tb), and I override touchesEnded:withEvent: like this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.tb reloadData];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

but I can't get a call of tableview:didselectrowatindexpath in such a way.
is reloaddata do sth influence the transfer of response chains? 
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 self.tableView.beginUpdates()
 self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

put this `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` method in the starting of your didSelect

Answer (score 0):

The call to `reloadData` deselects the selection.

Comment: I know reloaddata will call some method of datasource in next runloop, is the action of deselect the selection happens at once? thanks.

Comment: "I know reloaddata will call some method of datasource in next runloop" If you "know" that then you "know" wrong. `reloadData` causes the datasource methods to be called _immediately_, before we get to the next line.

Comment: really?i do a test with break point and i see reloaddata only cause numberofrowsinsection to be called immediately, then the next line be called before other datasource methods(cellforrowatindexpath) to be called. Is anything wrong with my operation?